# $( not executed when clicking links - need to Reload page every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found dozens of threads about this topic but non helped so far...

I am developing a web application using Jquery Mobile and ran into an issue.
I have this code snippet residing in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function prepareLinks() {
        $( "a.ajax" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.get($(this).attr( "href" ), '', function(data) {
                $("#content").html(data);
            });
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        alert('triggered');
        {if $autoload}
            $.get('{$autoload}', '', function(data) {
                $("#content").html(data);
                $("#content").trigger("create");
            });
        {/if}

        prepareLinks();
        if (screen.availWidth > 599) $( "#mainnav" ).panel( "open" );
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that `$(function() {` seems not to be executed when a user clicks a link (which is not ajax loaded) but only when the refresh the page by hand.

I also tried `<body onload="`as well as quick ans direty writing the code directly into the DOM... Nothing changed the issue...

Comment: `$(function() {` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {` ... which happens exactly once in a page lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Guess I found my problem... It's the integrated Ajax load feature I completely missed...

Answer (score 0):

It needs a trigger to actually start, as it is for the first function.
For example, on click of a "a" would trigger a foo function:

```
var foo = function(event){
   //your code here
}
$( "a" ).on( "click", foo );
```

Reference: https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/

Hope it helps !